# After Meteor.loginWithPassword old user does not go offline (meteor-user-status package)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a webpage where users can easily switch and login as another user. So I have this form that lets enter username/password and user is automatically signed into that new user. Here how I do it:

```
        'submit #loginForm': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var username = $("#usernameInput").val();
            var password = $("#passwordInput").val();
            var loginCallback = function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    FlashMessages.sendError(error.message);
                } else {
                    FlashMessages.sendSuccess("Logged in as " + username + " successfully");
                    Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            FlashMessages.sendError(error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, loginCallback);
        }
```

The problem is that the old user still stays online! What is the best way to solve this? Or I am missing something? Right now I am going with manually setting user offline before Meteor.loginWithPassword call and setting it back online if callback return error which does not seem very elegant solution.

Comment: Did you try to put this line of code `Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, loginCallback);` in the callback function of : `Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function(error) { ... Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, loginCallback); })` ? Maybe you've to wait until the current user is logged out.

Comment: OK my title was misleading. I modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thats what I did, not very happy with it but it works:

```
'submit #loginForm': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var username = $("#usernameInput").val();
            var password = $("#passwordInput").val();
            var loginCallback = function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    Meteor.call("goOnline");
                    FlashMessages.sendError(error.message);
                } else {
                    FlashMessages.sendSuccess("Logged in as " + username + " successfully");
                    Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            FlashMessages.sendError(error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            Meteor.call("goOffline"); // need to manually go offline as old user does not go offline after login
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, loginCallback);
            clearSession();
        }


'goOffline': function () {
        Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$set: {status: {online: false}}});
    },

    'goOnline': function () {
        Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$set: {status: {online: true}}});
    },
```